# timezone vs datetime in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

What is the difference between timezone and datetime?
`timezone.now()` returns `2016-09-26 16:20:27.211358+00:00`
`datetime.now()` returns `2016-09-26 21:50:27.211261`

Right now time in laptop clock is `21:50:27` ( 9 PM IST)

In my django settings file I have following settings.

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

Which one should I use to store time-stamp values in my database?
What if tomorrow someone in USA is using the code I am writing?
What should be the correct timezone settings in django settings file?

Comment: timezone.now() is more exact then datetime.now()

Comment: but i defined timezone as culcutta , and timezone.now() is showing 4 hours less than current time.

Comment: Wierd check your computer time, also check this out https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Or that could mean that because of +00:00 at the end it is using that timezone so maybe your in a + 4 time zone